# Where do apps store their "undo history" and how can I export it?

Tags: macos, undo-redo

I would like to export the "usage history" (or whatever the undo function uses to revert a  document to a previous state) of a currently open app. Where is that information stored, and how can I export it?

Sample apps for which I would like to be able to do this include Scrivener, Photoshop and Gimp.

Comment: Photoshop has an entire section in prefs devoted to 'history log' - https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgbH1.png - which I've never used so idk exactly what it saves or how much use it would be later.

Answer (score 4):

This is usually application-specific and not something which can be accessed from outside (and sometimes not even from within the application).

For Open Source tools like Gimp, you could add some code for this yourself (or have somebody do it). For closed source applications, you are out of luck unless the application itself has functionality for this.